# How to dynamically create new columns when column elements has more than 1 data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to dynamically add new tables when I select a data let's say my sql database has

```
Food       ingredients
----------------------
sandwich   Bread
sandwich   Butter
sandwich   Jam
```

but I don't want it to display like that when I use the select command I want it to look like this

```
Food       ingredients      ingredients2       ingredients3
------------------------------------------------------------
sandwich   Bread            Butter             Jam
```

Is it possible to do this?

Please teach it to me

Comment: dont do it, its a bad practice

Comment: @M.Ali i am actually doing this for when user is searching for One particular recipe so it will show all the ingredients along with the food name in one row

Answer (score 0):

I would create Three tables . `Food` , `Ingredients` and `Food_Ingredients`

---

Table `Food` should look something like....

```
FoodID     FoodName 
  1        sandwich
  2        Omelet
```

Make `FoodID` a Primary key

---

Table `Ingredient` should look something like....

```
IngredientID    IngredientName
     1           Bread
     2           Butter
     3           Jam
     4           Egg
     5           Oil
```

Make the IngredientID Primary key.

---

And finally the `Food_Ingredients` should look something like

```
FoodID   IngredientID
   1         1
   1         2
   1         3
   2         4
   2         2
```

Make both of these columns Foreign Keys to `Food` and `Ingredient` tables.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to look over your database design as suggested in the answer by M.Ali, but if you are only looking to retrieve data in a certain way then the query below should work for you. Note that it isn't dynamic in any way, so if you need more columns you have to add them manually. It would be possible to generate the columns in a dynamic fashion though.

```
select food, ingredient1, ingredient2, ingredient3
from (
    select 
       food,
       ingredients, 
       concat('ingredient', row_number() over (partition by food order by ingredients)) as cols
    from foodstuff
) t
pivot (
    max(ingredients) for cols in ([ingredient1],[ingredient2],[ingredient3]) 
) as p
```

Output:

```
food        ingredient1  ingredient2    ingredient3
sandwich    Bread        Butter         Jam
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses injection coding (please read up on the security risk potential).
Also credit @jpw for his answer contribution which I used to based the code on.
The code allows the number of ingredients to increase or decrease and will adjust.

```
DECLARE @col AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
select @col = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                    QUOTENAME('ingredients'+cast(row_number () over (partition by food order by ingredients) as varchar (max)))
                  FROM ##t1
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '')
 ;
 select @query =
 '
 select food, ' + @col + '
   from (
         select 
           food,
           ingredients, 
           ''ingredients''+ cast(row_number() over (partition by food order by ingredients)as varchar (10)) as cols
         from foodstuff
         ) t
 pivot (
        max(ingredients) for cols in (' + @col + ') 
        ) as p
 ;'
 ;
execute(@query);
```